# How can I redirect an error to different pages based on session data in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to Throw an Error on a path thanks to req.session.

This is what i've made but for a success action :

[set a element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bbok.png)

[set element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaTzc.png)

[element modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq29r.png)

And what i tried now is to throw an Error to tell me that 'there is no change on this element" when i dont do any change or forgot to change the element.
when i clicked on my button. It still show me "element changed"(success button, not danger button)

I want to send an error on a other path thanks to request.session.message

This is my code :

```
    routeur.post("/livres/modificationServer", (requete, reponse) => {
  const livreUpdate = {
    nom: requete.body.titre,
    auteur: requete.body.auteur,
    pages: requete.body.pages,
    description: requete.body.description,
  };
  livreSchema
    .updateOne({ _id: requete.body.identifiant }, livreUpdate)
    .exec()
    .then((resultat) => {
      if (resultat.nModified < 1)
        throw new Error("Requete de modification échouée");
      requete.session.message = {
        type: "success",
        contenu: "modification effectuée",
      };
      reponse.redirect("/livres");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      requete.session.message = {
        type: "danger",
        contenu: error.message,
      };
      reponse.redirect("/livres");
    });
});
```

this part don't want to go on the path /livres:

```
       .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      requete.session.message = {
        type: "danger",
        contenu: error.message,
      };
      reponse.redirect("/livres");
    });
```

when i clicked on my button. It still show me "element changed"(success button, not danger button)

I want to send an error on a other path thanks to request.session.message

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Just have to change `nModified` to `modifiedCount`.
I think nModified is deprecated.